# Magento 2 - Quantity in cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I tried to add a 'span' with the total quantity in cart but I have a small problem, I would like to add the red circle with quantity only if there is a product in cart. It works but when we go on another page, the red circle appears and disapears few seconds after.
Do you how I can solve this problem?

Here is my code in minicart.phtml

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="text"><?php echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
    <!-- ko if : getCartParam('summary_count') --><span class="cart-item-count circle circle-lg circle-red"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span><!-- /ko -->
</a>
```

[image]

one second after

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="text"><?= __('My Cart') ?></span>
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <span data-bind="text: getCartParam('summary_count'), css: 'cart-item-count circle circle-lg circle-red'"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</a>
```

CSS class with styles will be set only if 'summary_count' > 0.
I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="text"><?php echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="cart-item-count circle circle-lg circle-red"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
    <span class="counter-label">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
</a>
```